# Как разделить строку по знаку через .split?

Tags: java, split

Пытаюсь разделить строку по пайпу, почитал, как это все делается, но не могу понять, что не так. Не работает.

Пытаюсь разделить эту строку:

```
String test="23535|ghgdfh";
```

Когда вывожу эту строку в текствью, то проблем нет:

```
TextView test_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test_text);
test_text.setText(test);
```

Пытаюсь сделать по гуиду

```
TextView test_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test_text);
test_text.setText(test.split("|"));
```

В итоге студия ругается на cannot resolve method. 
Где я допускаю ошибку? И что можно почитать вообще по этому вопросу? Строки для чайников или типо того

Comment: split вернет массив, а setText принимает, наверняка, строку. Зачем разбивать строку на массив и сразу выводить ее?

Comment: @Grundy ну я просто упростил вопрос. Я получаю по блютузу две переменные, разделенные пайпом. Хочу вытащить эти переменные из строки и работать дальше с ними по отдельности

Comment: На будущее, оформляйте Java-код кнопкой «Пример кода» (`{}`), а не кнопкой «Фрагмент кода на JavaScript/HTML/CSS». Последняя предназначена только для интерактивных примеров на перечисленных языках, которые можно отобразить прямо в браузере.

Comment: @defaultlocale Так точно, сэр!)

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо Grundy за наводку. Нужно работать со строкой, а не с массивом

```
test_text.setText(Arrays.toString(test.split("\\|")));
```